# Como atualizar página e deixar seleção estática?

Tags: javascript, html

Eu tenho um select com algumas opções para criar um filtro, o que acontece é que quando atualizo a página o select volta para a primeira opção.Eu gostaria que quando eu atualiza-se a pagina permanece-se com a opção que eu havia selecionado antes. Seria possível?

Segue o código abaixo com a criação do select.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span id="tipo-filtro">Todos</span>
            <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
              <input data-label="Todos" checked value="all"
                id="tipo-filtro-todos" type="radio" name="tipo-filtro">
              <label for="tipo-filtro-todos">Todos</label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <input data-label="Fornecedor" value="1"
                id="tipo-filtro-fornecedor" type="radio" name="tipo-filtro">
              <label for="tipo-filtro-fornecedor">Fornecedor</label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <input data-label="Cliente Interno" value="2"
                id="tipo-filtro-cliente-interno" type="radio" name="tipo-filtro">
              <label for="tipo-filtro-interno">Cliente Interno</label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <input data-label="Cliente Externo" value="3"
                id="tipo-filtro-cliente-externo" type="radio" name="tipo-filtro">
              <label for="tipo-filtro-externo">Cliente Externo</label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <input data-label="Setor" value="4"
                id="tipo-filtro-setor" type="radio" name="tipo-filtro">
              <label for="tipo-filtro-setor">Setor</label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <input data-label="Principal" value="5"
                id="tipo-filtro-principal" type="radio" name="tipo-filtro">
              <label for="tipo-filtro-principal">Principal</label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <input data-label="Local" value="6"
                id="tipo-filtro-local" type="radio" name="tipo-filtro">
              <label for="tipo-filtro-local">Local</label>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <select multiple="multiple"
          class="doNotSelect2 selectmultiple form-control requester_mult_select"
          id="solicitante_os_filtro"
          style="width: 100%;"
          name="solicitante">
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Sim é possível, se vc tiver alguma interação com um banco de dados ou utilizar **localStorage**.

Answer (score 1):

Sim, você consegue fazer isso usando os *cookies* ou *localStorage*.

Aqui está um exemplo de como pode ser feito usando o *localStorage*.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select id="select">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <script>
      var select = document.getElementById("select");

      select.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
        localStorage.setItem("selected", e.target.value);
      });

      var opts = select.options;
      for (var opt, j = 0; opt = opts[j]; j++) {
        if (opt.value == localStorage.getItem("selected")) {
          select.selectedIndex = j;
          break;
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Vale a pena dar uma olhada nesse conteúdo sobre o Window.localStorage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage.

Também há essa pergunta sobre manipulação do `select` que vale a pena dar uma olhada: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373058/changing-the-selected-option-of-an-html-select-element